# Can we read data record by record from s3 buckets without storing the files in the local path?

Tags: cloud, talend

In Talend, Can we read data record by record (As we preview/read the data in source qualifier transformation in Informatica) from s3 buckets with out storing the files in the local path?

I am able fetch the files from s3 through Talend tool, So I want to know , How we can read "Record by Record" in Talend from s3.

Comment: Can you please provide an image of your job?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with a GIT repository by using tFileFetch componant (http protocol, use the cache to save the ressource) following by tFileInputExcel componant. In the tFileInputExcel componant, file name has to be the tFileFetch INPUT STREAM (which can be drag and drop from the Outline window). So, I guess that it's also possible with S3. Don't hesitate if your need more information.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, what you are looking for is a debugger like that of in informatica. use the following link to get what you are looking for:

https://help.talend.com/reader/93olCfmQi615MRwYBjy30g/ZkKg29u_lxKQUnFPjdCxBA